# Counting how many numbers are divisible by 3 in a list using recursion?

Tags: haskell

This is confusing me a lot here, I thnk I have an OK knowledge in haskell but I just cant get the whole "counting" part to work.

```
recursion :: [Int] -> Int
recursion [] = []
recursion (x:xs) = if x `mod` == 3 then.. +1 +  recursion xs
```

I know where its going wrong, the whole then +1 part but just cannot do it

count how many numbers are divisible by 3 in a giving list.

Comment: Look at your function signature, then at `recursion [] = []`. Don't you see something wrong? Your function doesn't return an `Int`.

Comment: What are you trying to do here anyway? Perhaps describe it in words.

Comment: @leftaroundabout count how many numbers are divisible by 3 in a giving list.

Comment: Oh, it's right in the title. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Use the empty list as an edge case where you return 0, so you can add 1 every time one element of the list is dividable by 3 without rest. If you can divide the element by 3 without rest you add 1 and call the function again with the list else you just add 0, e.g.

```
recursion :: [Int] -> Int
recursion [] = 0
recursion (x:xs) = if x `mod` 3 == 0 then 1 + recursion xs else 0 + recursion xs
```

Answer (score 6):

To write a recursive solution, you first need to consider the base case. As Vincent pointed out, you have a serious problem with your base case. The output `[]` has type `[a]`, but should have type `Int`. Ask yourself:

1. What type should the result have?
2. In an empty list, how many list elements are divisible by 3?

For the recursive case, it's unclear what you're missing, but it might just be syntax. You have the general idea.

```
recursion :: [Int] -> Int
recursion [] = -- base case goes here
recursion (x:xs) = if x `mod` 3 -- what is the type of (x `mod` 3)? Haskell isn't C!
                   then 1 + something
                   else somethingelse
```

Comment: its GCHI :) Thank you!

Comment: FTR, the OP does not contain ``if x `mod` 3 then ...``, but ``if x `mod` == 3 then ...`` (which is actually not even a valid expression, but if it were it would have the correct type `Bool`).

Comment: AH i was wondering why I kept getting parse errors on the '==', brilliant, thank you guys!